# Multivariable implicit function - Jacobi Matrix

Tags: calculus, analysis, derivatives, partial-derivative, implicit-function-theorem

> Find the derivate $f',f''$  of the implicit function $z=f(x,y)$ defined by the following equation:
>
> $$F(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2-a^2=0$$

So the first step to build the Jacobi-Matrix $f'$ lead me to this:
$$f'(x,y,z)=\begin{pmatrix} -\frac{x}{z} & -\frac{y}{z} \end{pmatrix}$$

I'm not sure in ranking the Jacobi-Matrix for $f''$:
First I derivated partial:
$$\partial_{xx} =-\frac{1}{z}, \partial_{yy}=-\frac{1}{z}, \partial_{xy}=\partial_{yx}=-1$$

For $\partial_z$ there isn't a function to derivate in fact of $f'$. So I got this:
$$f''(x,y)=\begin{pmatrix} -\frac{1}{z} & -1 \\ -1 & -\frac{1}{z} \end{pmatrix}$$

Any hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it is to just use the chain rule:

$$F(x,y,f(x,y))=x^2+y^2+[f(x,y)]^2-a^2=0$$

Differentiate with respect to $x$:

$$2x+2ff_x=0\qquad (1)$$

Differentiate with respect to $y$:

$$2y+2ff_y=0\qquad (2)$$

From these you get $f_x=-x/z$ and $f_y=-y/z$ as you say. (You could also use the formula from the implicit function theorem to get this result.)

To get $f_{xx}$, just differentiate $f_x=-x/(f(x,y))$ with respect to $x$:

$$f_{xx}=-\frac{f-xf_x}{f^2}$$

and then substitute $f=z$ and $f_x=-x/z$:

$$f_{xx}=-\frac{z+x^2/z}{z^2}=-\frac{x^2+z^2}{z^3}.$$

You can find the other derivatives in a similar way. It is pretty tedious.

Comment: I'm thankful for your answer. So $f_{xx}$ is the first entry in the Jacobi matrix?

Comment: It is the first entry in the Hessian (matrix of second order partial derivatives).